# Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-Enviroment-cd

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im using Virtual Studio Code and im  currently following this tutorial:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_debug-helloworldcpp

Im stuck at trying to debug my helloworld.cpp file. When i debug my file i get an error dialog saying:

Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-environment -cd. …". No such file or directory.

I think something might be wrong with my launch.json file

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "echo"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: the `mingw/bin` directory MUST be in the PATH for gdb to work. You can do it permanently or temporarily.

Comment: What do you mean with PATH, and permanently or temporarily?

Comment: environment variable PATH, add/append it in a terminal or in your system environment startup value

Comment: i think i have already done that

Comment: what is the full text of the terminal, the command plus the error message

Comment: I have already added a path in the system variables. dont know what you mean with terminal and command and error message